# multivariable calc review

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus

Haven't taken multivariable calculus in a way and just wanted to ask a question:

This looks like FTC for single variable (where you try to get the fcn of the integral out) but respect to two variables. What is this called / is there a proof of this / is this typically taught in a multi course. I only recall finding the derivative in a specific direction (directional derivatives).

[image]

Comment: It is the definition of a joint probability density function, so in a sense cannot have a proof

Comment: Well, you have to prove that integrating that function over a set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ gives $P((X, Y) \in S)$, since this is what density means. And by, say, Caratheodory's theorem, you really only have to consider the case when $S$ is a rectangle $[a_1, b_1] \times [a_2, b_2]$. At this point, the fundamental theorem of calculus helps.

Comment: If you are asking about the notation $$\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}F(x,y)$$ it just means "Hold $x$ constant and take the derivative with respect to $y$. Then, hold $y$ constant in that derivative and take another derivative with respect to $x$". $\partial$ is used instead of $d$ in the derivative to remind us that the result of this derivative depends not only on the variable being differentiated, but also the variable being held constant. Letting $x = u - y$ and taking $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}F$ while holding $u$ constant gives a different answer than holding $x$ constant.